# Given an AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment, how do I get the auto scaling Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an Elastic Beanstalk environment with auto scaling.

I need the identity of the autoscaling group so that I can build graphs and alarms around it using CloudWatch.

Given Elastic Beanstalk environment, how do I get the auto scaling group?

I can use the web console or the CLI.

Comment: You want to check the Available Auto scaling group or you want to create a Autoscaling group?

Comment: When you go into the EC2 web console and view your autoscaling groups, are you having trouble figuring out which one was created by Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

I believe elastic beanstalk will automatically tag the ASG with the environment name. This worked for me:

`aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --filters Name=tag-value,Values=YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_NAME`